# Unable to pass complex object from Angular to Nodejs in get method

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-routing, angular5

I am trying to pass an object from angular to node js in the following code:

**Angular:**

```
let data = {module: "master",identifier: "personneltype"};

return this._http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/Personnel/GetGlobalConfig",{params:data})  
.map((response:Response)=><IGlobalConfig[]>response.json())
 .catch(this.handleError);
```

**Node:**

```
function getGlobalConfig(req, res, next) {
    pool.connect(function (err, client, done) {
        var q ='select * from abc.table($1:: character varying(150), $2:: character varying(150))';
        client.query(q,[req.params.module,req.params.identifier], function (err, result) {
            done();
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.status(400).send(err);
            }
            res.status(200).send(result.rows);
        });
    });
};
```

**Route:**

```
router.get('/getGlobalConfig/:module&:identifier',db.getGlobalConfig);//not sure what this should be
```

**While this angular code works:**

```
let data = {module: "master",identifier: "personneltype"};

    return this._http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/Personnel/GetGlobalConfig/"+data.module+"&"+data.identifier)  
    .map((response:Response)=><IGlobalConfig[]>response.json())
     .catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: Did you check the developers console for the actual request URL that's being used for #1 compared to #2? I suspect `params` should be of type https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
let data = new HttpParams();
data = data.append('module', 'master');
data = data.append('identifier', 'personneltype');

return this._http.get("http://localhost:3000/api/Personnel/GetGlobalConfig",{params:data})  
.map((response:Response)=><IGlobalConfig[]>response.json())
 .catch(this.handleError);
```